# How to shift the circular hole of Dupin cyclide while keeping the curve circular without deformation?

Tags: analytic-geometry, parametrization

I have been interested in studying parametric functions. But when I dealt with Dupin cyclide, I found it difficult to shift the circular hole, for example, if I wanted to shift it towards the x-axis or the y-axis. There is always a deformation of Dupin's torus and it is close to the shape of the ellipse and it always needs adjustment. Is there a better way to do that.

\begin{align}
x(u,v) &= \frac{d(c - a\cos u \cos v) + b^2 \cos u}{a - c \cos u \cos v}, \\
y(u,v) &= \frac{b\sin u (a-d\cos v)}{a - c \cos u \cos v},\\
z(u,v) &= \frac{b\sin v (c\cos u - d)}{a - c \cos u \cos v}.
\end{align}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to translate the focal conics**

- The first conic is focus-origin:

$$A=
\left(
  \frac{(1+e)\cos u}{1+e\cos u},
  \frac{(1+e)\sin u}{1+e\cos u},
  0
\right)$$

- The second conic is vertex-origin:

$$B=
\left(
  \frac{e(1+\cos v)}{e-\cos v},
  0,
  \frac{(1+e)\sin v}{e-\cos v}
\right)
$$

- Divide $AB$ with the ratio $m:n$ gives the Dupin cyclide where

\begin{align}
  m &= \frac{e(1-\cos u)}{1+e\cos u}+k \\
  n &= \frac{1+e}{e-\cos v}-k
\end{align}

- For the circular hole centres at the origin,

$$k,e \in (0,1)$$

- For a torus,

$$e=0$$

- For a parabolic Dupin cyclide,

$$e=1$$

- Please also refer to *Wikipedia* article [*here*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dupin_cyclide#Derivation_of_the_parametric_representation).

Comment: Could you give the parametric equations for the surface.

Comment: Try to evaluate $$C=\frac{nA+mB}{m+n}$$ by CAS (such as *Wolfram Alpha*) as an exercise.